# Uniform continuity on $[c,d] \subseteq (a,b)$ implies UC on $(a,b)$ and UC on $[a,b] \ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ implies UC on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Is it true that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[c,d] \subseteq (a,b)$ then it is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$? Furthermore, is it true that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b] \ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

How would I go about proving these two statements?

Comment: Do you mean $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$ for every $c,d\in (a,b)$?

Comment: Nope, specific $c,d$. I got that convoluted in my head, seems obvious to me not to be the case then that if something is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ it doesnt have to be on $(-1,2)$. Not sure if the question from my textbook is incomplete or if it just is that simple. Thoughts on the second question?

Comment: For the second question, note that any continuous function on $\Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous on any closed interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Oh, so if given an $\varepsilon > 0$ I know that for each $[a,b]$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ that would satisfy that $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$ and I would then simply take the minimum of all the deltas to make it work on $\mathbb{R}$?

Edit: I can see that is clearly wrong but I dont really understand why.

Comment: The thought about taking the minimum isn't justified. 
The key for such reasoning is compactness .

Comment: Thank you, its making sense now. I guess I just need a better intuition of the way real numbers behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: $$f:[1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$$
is uniformly continuous. But 
$$f:]0,3[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$$
is not uniformly continuous. 
If you meant for every $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$ then it is still not true:
$$\forall [c,d] \subset (0,+\infty): f:[c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$$ is uniformly continuous.

**For the second:**
$$\forall [c,d] \subset (0,+\infty): g:[c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \rightarrow e^{x}$$ is uniformly continuous.
But
$$g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \rightarrow e^{x}$$ is not.

Let's see why this is a counterexample:
Given: $\epsilon>0$, we search: 
$$\delta>0 : \forall |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |e^{x}-e^{y}|<\epsilon$$
This can be rewritten:
$$|e^{x}-e^{y}|<\epsilon$$
$$e^{y}-\epsilon<e^{x}<e^{y}+\epsilon$$
Taking the $ln$ (assuming $e^{y}-\epsilon>0$):
$$ln(e^{y}-\epsilon)<x<ln(e^{y}+\epsilon)$$
Take $x = y+\frac{\delta}{2}$.
Then:
$$ln(e^{y}-\epsilon)<y+\frac{\delta}{2}<ln(e^{y}+\epsilon)$$
$$ln(e^{y}-\epsilon)-y<\frac{\delta}{2}<ln(e^{y}+\epsilon)-y$$
Taking the limit as $y \rightarrow \infty$:
$$0\leq\frac{\delta}{2}\leq0$$
Thus no such $\delta$ exists.
The problem why this doesn't work, is that $e^{x}$ increases more reapidly when $x$ gets bigger.

Comment: Thanks,  I guess that is quite obvious. Thoughts on the second question?

Comment: See my edit, for the second question.

Comment: Thank you, I see now that it doesnt work but I'm not entirely sure I understand why that is. Is there any way to formally prove it or would a counterexample be sufficient?

Comment: Giving a counterexample, and proving it is in fact a counterexample is the best way. Proving in general seems  hard to do for me.

Comment: See my edit, why this is a counterexample.